# How do you check for a line of text in text files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I am receiving no errors, but it does not seem to check for the text in my file, as it will append anything you input. Can anyone help?

```
guest_name = input("What is your name: ")
with open("guests.txt", "a+") as guests_txt:

    names = guests_txt.readlines()


    def find_name():
        if guest_name.lower() in names:
            print("Your name is already taken.")
            name_taken = True
            return name_taken

    name_taken_function = find_name()

    if not name_taken_function:
        guests_txt.write(f"{guest_name.lower()}\n")
```

Comment: where is `guest_name` defined?

Comment: I didn't get that part pasted in i got it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this much more simply than a lot of these other answers.

```
guest_name = input("What is your name: ")
with open("guests.txt", "a+") as guest_txt:
    guest_txt.seek(0)
    names = guest_txt.read().splitlines()
    if guest_name.lower() in names:
        print(f"Sorry, {guest_name}, your name is already taken.")
    else:
        guest_txt.write(f"{guest_name.lower()}\n")
        print(f"Thanks, {guest_name}, your name has been recorded.")
```

Comment: The answer is great, but in the case when the file is empty, an empty line on the top is created when a new name is added.

Answer (score 6):

The mode `a+` opens the file for append, so when you open it, the current position is at the end of the file. `readlines()` returns an empty list.

You should do `guests_txt.seek(0)` before reading it.

Comment: I am still left with the same result, I put `guests_txt.seek(0)` at the beginning of opening the file, but I can still put it the same strings.

Comment: @iLikeToCode123465 include the contents of `guests.txt` in your post.

Answer (score 2):

When you're opening a file with `a+`, position is set at the last character. When you try to read it, as there's nothing else after that last character, you will get an empty text.

Use `guests_txt.seek(0)` to seek to the beginning, and then read.
Another problem is, `.readlines()` won't strip `\n` character. Instead you can use `.read().splitlines()` to get the lines without newline character:

```
guest_name = input("What is your name: ")
with open("guests.txt", "a+") as guests_txt:

    guests_txt.seek(0)
    names = guests_txt.read().splitlines()

    def find_name():
        if guest_name.lower() in names:
            print("Your name is already taken.")
            name_taken = True
            return name_taken

    name_taken_function = find_name()

    if not name_taken_function:
        guests_txt.write(f"{guest_name.lower()}\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to append new name you can use `guests_file.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)`. Also I would recommend to simplify the code and improve names:

```py
guest_name = input("What is your name: ").lower()
with open("guests.txt", "a+") as guests_file:
    guests_file.seek(0)
    names = guests_file.readlines()

    def name_is_taken():
        if guest_name + '\n' in names:
            print("Your name is already taken.")
            return True

    if not name_is_taken():
        guests_file.write(f"{guest_name}\n")
```

Comment: I have just removed unnecessary lines also. @patmcb answer is great, but in the case when the file is empty, an empty line on the top is created when a new name is added.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because the `.readlines()` method doesn't strip away the extra `'\n'`, and so, the name input by the user will never be equal to the existing ones. Use `.read().splitlines()` instead. Also, try opening the file twice, once in read mode, and then in append mode:

```
guest_name = input("What is your name: ")

with open("guests.txt", "r") as guests_txt:
    name_taken = False
    names = guests_txt.read().splitlines()
    if guest_name.lower() in names:
        if guest_name.lower() in names:
            print("Your name is already taken.")
            name_taken = True

with open("guests.txt", "a") as guests_txt:
    if not name_taken:
        guests_txt.write(f"\n{guest_name.lower()}")
```

Comment: Although, for some reason, the only way `name_taken` would be defined, is if you define it at the start of opening the file in read mode.

Comment: That's because there are two `if guest_name.lower()` statements. This code is also inefficient. Please see my answer.

Comment: No problem! @AnnZen